# how to print class object in c++? I have refine the <<

Tags: c++

in class test:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Test& test){
    os<<"hooooo"<<endl;
    return os;
}
```

in test code:

```
Test t2 = Test(10, 20);
```

why `cout<< t2 <<endl` compile pop error? I have refine the <<.

no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << t2'

Comment: When you say "in class test", do you mean that you've defined it as a member function of the `Test` class?  Don't do that, make it a free function.  `operator<<` is a binary operator.  It takes a left hand argument, and a right hand argument.  When you make it a member function, the left hand argument is implied.  It is the calling object.  If that's not the problem here, give a complete example of your code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually define it as a friend function.  Operators have to be defined by the operand that preceeds the operator.  So you define it with the `friend` keyword so that the function can still muck around with the innards of your class, but work the way it needs to.  I'm sorry if I'm not very clear, its been a while since I've done this.  Not sure where you are supposed to put the body of the function either.  Just look up the `friend` keyword.

Comment: No, you don't need to define it as a friend.  Some would say you should, and I would disagree with them.  But they and I would both agree that it's certainly not necessary.

Comment: OK, thank you, I never really learned that part of c++ very well (mostly because my textbook was one of the type that is only useful for burning)